# javascript moment separate date and time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment-timezone and this is the code:

```
$('#myDiv').text(moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

This will output something like this:

```
06-10-2017 08:44:15
```

What I want to do is to put the date and time in 2 different elements but at this point it's all together in the same output.

How can I do this with moment?

Comment: You can simply concat your strings and then parse it with moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your can use

```
var datetime = moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').split(' ');
```

and the value of datetime is
    ['06-10-2017', '08:44:15']

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
$('#myDateDiv').text(moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
$('#myTimeDiv').text(moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

Or if you wanted to call `moment` only once you could split up the result by the space between the date and time:

```
var datetime = moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS').split(' ');
$('#myDateDiv').text(datetime[0]);
$('#myTimeDiv').text(datetime[1]);
```